# equivalent sub-keys in DES encryption

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, cryptography, encryption

i am trying to understand the DES cryptosystem and was wondering: what would've happened if all of the sub-keys were equal? does it reduce the security? can we actually find the keys if we know all the sub keys are equal?

can we make this any securer if for instance we run DES twice?

if you can give me a mathematical explanation it would help me a lot in understanding why things are happening so i can better understand this algorithm.

thank you much for assistance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_key#Weak_keys_in_DES

Comment: That is known as [slide attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/63629/18298)